# How do i make it not come up with an error if weight entered is not in the list(index error)

Tags: python

Can you please help me with my problem and make it ask me to enter another weight if it is not on the list or not in the same index point.
Thank you for your help.
This my code:

```
coins = [2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

weights = [120, 175, 160, 250, 325, 325, 356, 356]

a = []
found = False
foundd = False
loop = "yes"
bags = 0
ans = "no"
ansb = "no"
coina = 0


while loop == "yes":

    name = input("What is your name?")

    coin = float(input("What coin is it?"))

    weight = float(input("How much does the bag weigh?"))

    for x in coins:
        if coin == x:
            found = True
            print("coin right")

        if found == False:
            print("coin wrong")


    if weights.index(weight)==coins.index(coin):
        foundd = True
        print("weight right")
    else:
        print("weight wrong")

    coina = coina + coin
    bags += 1

    newList = [name, coin, weight]

    a.append (newList)

    ans = input("Do you want to see the list with everyones names and amount of coins with weight?(yes?/no)")
    ansb = input("Do you want to see amount of bags put in and coin value?(yes/no)")

    if ans == "yes":
        for i in a:
            print(i)
    if ansb == "yes":
        print(bags,"£",coina)


    loop = input("Do you want to enter another coin?(yes/no)")
```

(ignore this it won't let me post this unless i write more.)

Comment: You should generally never compare `float`s via `==`. They are not exact values, but approximations.

Comment: it would seem more natural to store the coins and their respective weights in a dictionary rather than 2 lists

Comment: You have your `found` and `foundd` variables that tell you if you found a match. Put the `input` in a loop until `found` or `foundd` (depending on the input meaning) are true

Comment: also you can use integers instead of float, assuming `0.01` is 1 cent/pence/etc. then make that value 1 and adjust all other values correspondingly

Comment: `if x in coins:` can replace your `foundd` stuff

Comment: @Chris_Rands While you're correct in what you say, I think that at this beginner level, he should take things one step at a time.

Comment: @ChatterOne What advanced feature did I introduce? Seems pretty straightforward

Comment: @Chris_Rands There's a big chance that dictionaries are still to come in next lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dicta = { 
    2: 120, 1: 175, 0.5: 160, 0.2: 250, 0.1: 325, 0.05: 325,0.02: 356, 0.01: 356
}

while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ")

    coin = 'a'    
    while coin not in dicta.keys():
        try:
            coin = float(input("What coin is it ?"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid input")

    weight = 'a'    
    while weight not in dicta.values():
        try:
            weight = float(input("How much does the bag weigh?"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid input")

    if weight == dicta[coin]:
        print("Weight right.")
    else:
        print("Weight wrong")
```

I would suggest building off a skeleton like this, also you should look into `try, except` and how you are applying them

Answer (score 0):

You should try that:

```
coins = [2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

weights = [120, 175, 160, 250, 325, 325, 356, 356]

a = []
found = False
foundd = False
loop = "yes"
bags = 0
ans = "no"
ansb = "no"
coina = 0


while loop == "yes":

    name = input("What is your name?")

    #ask for coin and check if it is in the list...
    coin = float(input("What coin is it?"))
    try: 
        coins.index(coin)
    except:
        print('Coin not in the list...')
        coin = float(input("What coin is it?"))

    #ask for weight and check if it is in the list...
    weight = float(input("How much does the bag weigh?"))
    try: 
        weights.index(weight)
    except:
        print('Weight not in the list...')
        weight = float(input("How much does the bag weigh?"))

    for x in coins:
        if coin == x:
            found = True
            print("coin right")

        if found == False:
            print("coin wrong")

    if weights.index(weight)==coins.index(coin):
        foundd = True
        print("weight right")
    else:
        print("weight wrong")
[...]
```

The problem is that you can only make one mistake.

I feel like the simplest is to implement your own index function with a `for` loop. This function would return the index or `None` if the element is not found. That way you can ask the user input `while` the value is `None`.

Comment: This will fail if the wrong value is input multiple times. You should have a loop that checks the validity of the input.